# How to convert an image for .tflite input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get the model (which ran successfully before it was converted to.tflite) to classify test images.

```
img = Image.open( input_path )
img.load()
input_data = np.array(img, dtype=np.int32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
```

But I get an error *ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got tensor of type 2 but expected type 1 for input 13*

This refers to the dtype, and I believe int32 is the correct format, I've tried nearly every other but I still get the error, which isn't very descriptive.

As I have the dtype correct, I presume that I must be converting the image incorrectly. Is there a better way I should be converting this image to submit to the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
input_data = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
```

You can always check with

```
print(interpreter.get_input_details())
```

which dtype is required